# How to create the illusion of depth with repeating patterns?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

How do I create perspective with repeating patterns? I am very much a beginner level, as noted by my first attempt to create a illustration in illustrator. However, my attempt has provided me with various questions and obstacles on how to achieve the  Hand-drawn illustration.

For instance, in the picture below – there is repeating previously design pattern. What technique could be used to create depth?

[image: comp idea]

The end result should yield a perspective similar to this live trace.  This may be off topic so please let me know how far or nebulous this question appears. 
[image]

[image: Edited to folloe perspective guides.]

Comment: I think you are right. Should I delete this to keep the topics relevant and avoid redundancy?

Comment: @Charles nope, deletion is not necessary. It is better to keep duplicates around, it makes it easier for others to find them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you only referring to the brick fireplace? A sense of depth needs a reasonably good understanding of perspective. And light. And composition. Regardless of texture. In this case, I would say your room is one-point perspective. Allow me to go through some principles, even though they may not seem wildly relevant. They are, though..

Principle of perspectives:

[image]

**Perspective:**

Even if you start out with a photo, it is important to keep an eye on the actual composition and how this affects the perspective. We handle a 3d world every day without effort, so the complexity of what it *really looks like* can be actually hard to grasp.

You have a horizon-line. It will be at the eye-height of the observer. Not the observer of the *image*, but the observer through which eyes we see the image. I.e. the artist/photographer.

Essentially, thus:

[image]

So, your images has an imagined horizon line and a vanishing point. Things in the image will be "distorted" according to the perspective. As an example; the carpet. I have here used a different pattern. Rectangles, to make it easier to see what happens. The carpet is reasonably easy, as it is pretty 2-dimensional. The great fun starts with 3d-objects.

[image]

Your image would kinda be based on this model of perspective. So, everything "vanishes" into the vanishing point. Hence the name:

[image]

This might make it a little easier to visualise:

[image]

**Composition:**

Just my two pennies: regarding composition, what is absolutely necessary for a sense of depth, apart from a reasonably good perspective, is to place things *in front of each other*. Not lots of stuff in a jumble, but simply do not align the edges of things. In your image you have the sofas/settees well placed (personally, I would angle the left one a little, just to make the composition a little more interesting.).

Since your vanishing point is pretty much in the dead centre of the image, you will not see the sides of the fireplace (I assume it has sides, at least a brick width sticking out from the wall). If you moved your vanishing point a little to one side, the depth would be clearer, and it would make for a more interesting image. This, of course will have a large influence on the texture of your brick: if you angle the perspective a little, the light-shadow will change.

Hope this helps. Light, is an entire book in itself.

**Arty-farty addendum:**

A classic horror film from when film was silent, is called [The cabinet of dr. Caligari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cabinet_of_Dr._Caligari) what I find so brilliant about it, apart from the obvious historic view, is the way the sets are made, and the glorious use of crazy skewed perspective. Here are two images, and yes, the people are actors :-D So there are rules to perspective, and joy in going bananas and breaking them. The sets are used as a canvas to heighten the sense of horror and off-ness:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is tremendously helpful. It will take a little while to digest and apply your knowledge. However, the integration of the diagrams along with your explanation really helps clear up some of my misconceptions. I think I need to start with just one element – the carpet for instance and work backwards from there. I think I also will remove all colors to focus on the composition and then added in later for I find my eyes are distracted by choice.

Comment: I'm going to play around a bit and update my really rough composition as a learning exercise. I know this is not following the strict protocol of the exchange but it does answer my question and adds greater context to which the question lacks.

Comment: Oh, goodie :-) glad to be of help, would like to know how you get on. I find it easiest to scribble on paper first (but I am hopelessly old school). To have depth in texture alone, need a little understanding of perspective, but also of light :-S it gets pretty complicated quickly, but do not be discouraged. It all depends on what you want to achieve. Keep your old files, even if you think they are bad, and you can go back to them later. It is useful as an exercise in visual understanding. Oh, and perspective is most fun when you break it knowingly. I will add a sidenote to my answer.

Comment: Woh! I see you are an artist! nice stuff! I have some more comments, but I think it would be better moved to chat, if you are interested.

Comment: yes, definitely, lets chat. I'm going to play around with this comp over the next few days.

Comment: i am a bit of a noob in setting up chat, but try this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12445/perspective-texture

Comment: @boblet- I updated the image. Am i getting closer? The rug pattern didn't follow the 3d-distort.

Comment: I added some comments here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12445/perspective-texture

Comment: In the duplicate question: What Parameters inside the 3-D scale effect were used? I've been playing with the various prospective choices but simply want the hexagons that are closest to the bottom of the picture to be the largest and for them to slowly get smaller as the pattern gets close to the fireplace. This must be a very resource intensive affect, for it takes a few minutes and has a severe lag time.